# Bad answers discourage others from answering

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I ask a question like: "How can I train my cat to jump 2 meters high? I know I could kick it hard, but is there another way?".

Then I get two answers: "I think you want your cat to jump 2 meters high" and "when you kick it hard enough, it will jump that high". Sometimes they even get upvotes, because both the answerer and the viewers are ADHD-driven guys unable to read and understand any text longer than 2 sentences.

Then no-one else is going to look at that question, because it "has" an answer. And after a few such questions I will be spanked for low accept ratio.

How do you deal with it? All I can do is downvote or talk the "answerer" into removing the question, but usually it doesn't work.

Can we get a "I hate this answer, please don't count it on the main page" button or something?

**EDIT** - some examples:

- [File-based equivalent of java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009152/file-based-equivalent-of-java-util-concurrent-locks-lock)
- [Can properties mapped in hbm.xml be transient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659594/can-properties-mapped-in-hbm-xml-be-transient)
- [Eclipse - see which methods of one class are used in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530750/eclipse-see-which-methods-of-one-class-are-used-in-another)

Comment: You got any real example?

Comment: `Can we get a "I hate this answer, please don't count it on the main page" button or something?` That's what the down vote arrow is for.  I realize that your problem is the answers are getting up voted and your down vote may not mean much, but this is still a community site, and you'll have to deal with the fact that not everyone will agree with you everytime. If you feel your questions aren't sufficiently answered because of existing sub par answers, well, then your best bet would be to place a bounty on it.

Comment: [Are upvotes and downvotes different on meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: `Why the downvotes?` Well, for one, I don't like the animal abuse theme...

Comment: "And after a few such questions I will be spanked for low accept ratio." - The accept rate police have resorted to spanking now?  Geez, they were annoying enough with just comments.  As one who used to be among their ranks, please accept my apologies on their behalf.  They know not what they do.

Comment: The downvotes are a sign of disagreement. Basically people are disagreeing with the concept of an 'I hate this answer' button.

Answer (score 11):

After looking at the answers in your examples I can't see your problem. The answers all look well intentioned to me. Some of them miss the point sometimes, but that is usual and further clarification is given after you comment.

After reading this question I was expecting facetious, useless answers, but that isn't the case. Maybe you are being a bit over sensitive?

I had to re-read your questions several times to understand them, so perhaps improving the way you ask questions will get better answers. I am a big believer in the quality of answers reflecting the quality of the question (mostly). I say this in the spirit of constructive criticism, I hope you will accept it as such.